# Code Coverage in VS2022 and SonarQube using test frameworks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, sonarqube, code-coverage

We are using VS2022 for .net core web api application where we are planning to use any of the following unit test frameworks for unit testing and cove coverage. Also, the project will be configured on SonarQueb to see the detailed cove coverage.

1. XUnit
2. NUnit
3. MSTest

However, after doing some analysis we have observed that these tools doesnt actually give you the code coverage. These are used to write unit test cases only and not for code coverage.

So, the question is If we want to have the detailed code coverage on SonarQube for the configured project, then what are the alternative/additional things we need to implement?

As what we have understood writing only test cases is not going to provide actual code coverage.

Any help on this appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

The testing frameworks by themselves won't give you code coverage unless you are running the tests with Visual Studio Enterprise.

Thankfully, there is an open-source solution called [coverlet](https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet). Install the `coverlet.collector` nuget package in your unit test projects and generate coverage reports with `dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"`.

Look at their extensive documentation if you want to know about combining reports, generating html pages from your results, and more.